# Show that $\mathbb{R}|_{\sim}$ is uncountable for $\sim (x, y) : y - x \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I'm self-learning some measure theory. During the following lecture ( I had included the appropriate starting time inside the link, but timespan is 7:50-9:00):

https://youtu.be/llnNaRzuvd4?t=470

the Professor Claudio Landim states that if we take $\Lambda = \mathbb{R}|_{\sim}$ where $\sim (x, y)  :  y - x \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $\Lambda$ is uncountable. The lecturer explains that if indeed $\Lambda$ was countable, then every element in $\mathbb{R}$ could be represented by element of $\Lambda$ (some equivalence class) and by element of this equivalence class. Couldn't it? Why not? I cannot understand it.

Comment: Start with working out the *size* of any particular equivalence class.  Then, as the lecturer is pointing out, how big would the union of a countable number of these equivalence classes be?

Comment: @hardmath somehow I figured out that size of an equivalence class is uncountable... and Surb proved me wrong. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notations are not so clear. $$\mathbb R/_\sim=\{[x]\mid x\in \mathbb R\},$$
and $$[x]=\{y\in \mathbb R\mid y-x\in \mathbb Q\}.$$

So, what you want to prove is that $\Lambda :=\mathbb R/_\sim$ is uncountable. Suppose $\Lambda $ is countable, i.e. $\mathbb R/_\sim=\{[x_n]\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for some $x_n$. In one hand, if $x\in \mathbb R$, then $[x]=x+\mathbb Q$ is countable. In the other hand, if $\Lambda $ is countable, then $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of countable set, and thus $\mathbb R$ would be countable, which is a contradiction.

Comment: like I mentioned to hardmath, for some reason I assumed the size of equivalence class is uncountable... Thank you! I'll try to fix my notation in the future